# Getting Regex error on VB.NET on a specific string

Tags: regex, vb.net

Can someone help me please? I want to understand what could have made this regex match stop before showing whether there's a match or not.

So, I'm using Regex and it looks like i'm stuck on an infinite loop.

Here's the pattern and string to match. A match shouldn't be found on this case, i verified that manually.

```
pattern = "((^)|([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\((([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))(\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *(([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)))*\)\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *)+)(\()*((([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *)*([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*))"

string = "(SUM(UTRANCELL.PMNORABESTABLISHATTEMPTPACKETSTREAM)+SUM(UTRANCELL.PMNORABESTABLISHATTEMPTPACKETSTREAM128)+SUM(UTRANCELL.PMNORABESTABLISHATTEMPTPACKETINTERACTIVE)+SUM(UTRANCELL.PMNORABESTATTEMPTSSTREAMHS))"
```

Here's the grammar i used to build the regex:

```
<formula_com_erro> ::= ( <inicio_linha> | (<subformula> ['+'|'-'|'*'|'/'])+ ) {'('} ( { (<constante_numerica>)  ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/') } ( <alias> '.' <contador> ) ) 
<formula_com_erro> ::= ((^)|([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\((([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))(\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *(([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)))*\)\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *)+)(\()*((([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *)*([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*))
<subformula> ::= <nome_funcao> '(' (<alias> '.' <contador>) | (<constante_numerica>) {['+'|'-'|'*'|'/'] ((<alias> '.' <contador>) | (<constante_numerica>))} ')' 
<subformula> ::= [A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\((([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))(\ *[\+\-\*\/]\ *(([A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*\.[A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)))*\)
<nome_funcao> ::= ( <letra> | <digito> | '_' )+ 
<nome_funcao> ::= [A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*
<alias> ::= ( <letra> | <digito> | '_' )+ 
<alias> ::= [A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*
<contador> ::= ( <letra> | <digito> | '_' )+ 
<contador> ::= [A-z0-9_]*[A-z][A-z0-9_]*
<constante_numerica> ::= ( <digito> )+
<constante_numerica> ::= [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: [`[A-z]` matches `_`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970), you must have meant `[A-Za-z]`. However, the pattern you have just causes catastrophic backtracking since there are lot of subsequent quantified subpatterns that may match the same text.

Comment: Are you using VB.NET or NotePad++?

Comment: I think i might have just resolved this problem. I reduced the ammount of context verified at each iteration, by changing this production rule (removing the symbol + after <subformula> rule):

`<formula_com_erro> ::= ( <inicio_linha> | (<subformula> ['+'|'-'|'*'|'/']) ) {'('} ( { (<constante_numerica>)  ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/') } ( <alias> '.' <contador> ) )`